# Android Studio: App crashes after adding Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, crash

I've tried soo much searching for a solution but there's no solution that sovled my problem!

My app works fine but I want to add the result in the `TextView` to a Firebase.
After I add the Firebase to my Java code, app crashes with the message "App Unfotunatlly stopped" and I open the app on a real device!

Here's my Java code with the added Firebase:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener ,ValueEventListener {

//here is the added firebase that cause the error -_-
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
private DatabaseReference buslocationRef = myRef.child("master");

Button getLocationBtn;
TextView locationText, test1;

LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...........................

}
}
```

and my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
}
```

plus, I've updated my Android Studio to the latest version 3.0!!

I hope you can help me with this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @PeterHaddad how to do it???
you mean the same codes as I wrote above?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I put it inside put still, the same pblm =|

Comment: what is the error in the logcat?

Comment: Post Logcat here

Comment: Thankx God it works finally!
The only reason was in the app Gradle and the codes wasn't orginaized very well ^^
Thanks for the help and support!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing google-services version to 4.2.0 in build.gradle(project version).